# Question about Random function

Tags: c#, random

I'm new to programming in C#. My question is this;

how can i, after generating random numbers (i got so far), get these numbers to show random images in imageboxes?

I have 4 imageboxes with a backgroundimage. (but i want them to change, according to the numbers i generate).

How do i do that?

Anybody got an idea?

Thx in advance!!

Comment: In what range you random number will come??

Answer (score 7):

Keep a list of images, and set the image to a random element in the list:

```
public class SomeHostingForm
{
    private readonly List<Image> images; // Populate elsewhere...
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    private void SwitchImage(ImageBox box)
    {
        box.Image = images[random.Next(images.Count)];
    }
}
```

(I'm not sure exactly which type you're talking about, so this is somewhat pseudo-code.)

Answer (score 3):

Put the imageboxes in an array, then use the random number as the index of the array to get a random imagebox.